# Problem with joining to an empty table

Tags: mysql, join

I use the following query:

```
select * from A LEFT JOIN B on ( A.t_id != B.t_id)
```

to get all the records in A that are not in B.

The results are fine except when table B is completely empty, but then I do not get any records, even from table A.

## Later

**It won't work yet!**

#### Table structure for T1

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `T1` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `t_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
```

#### Dumping data for table `T1`

```
INSERT INTO `T1` (`id`, `title`, `t_id`) VALUES
(1, 'apple', 1),
(2, 'orange', 2);
```

#### Table structure for table `T2`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `T2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `t_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
```

#### Dumping data for table `T2`

```
INSERT INTO `T2` (`id`, `title`, `t_id`) VALUES
(1, 'dad', 2);
```

#### Operations

Now I want to get all records in T1 that do not have a corresponding records in T2.

I try

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.t_id != T2.t_id
```

and it won't work.

Comment: So, you're saying your query with the LOJ doesn't work when the second (outer) table is not empty, and it also doesn't work when the second (outer) table is empty.  Or, in other words, your query with LOJ does not work - period?

Comment: If you want to get T1 records that don't have a match in T2, use `SELECT T1.* FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.id = T2.id WHERE T2.id IS NULL`, the 3rd option from Unreason great answer

Comment: You need to learn not to use useless phrases like "it [doesn't] work". Describe what you see, what you expect, and what you think the difference is.

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from A where t_id not in (select t_id from B)
```

Comment: As my understanding he wants both tables if exists and just have one special case that B is empty.

Comment: @YvesR this make no sense as he specified that he wants only records from A that are *not* in B, so using an join here will always lead in fields of B to be NULL

Comment: +1: This is the general way of finding the rows in A that are not in B.  If B is empty, all the rows from A are selected.  It also has the merit of not selecting a fine set of NULL values for the columns in B, whereas the 'SELECT * FROM A ... JOIN B' includes them.

Comment: Yes it seems to work, also waiting for an answer from user Unreason

Answer (score 3):

Your have two problems

**1) Wrong diagnosis**

Given two tables

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE T1 (ID INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)
mysql> CREATE TABLE T2 (ID INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)
mysql> INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

the query

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID != T2.ID;
+------+------+
| ID   | ID   |
+------+------+
|    1 | NULL |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

returns the non-matched rows even though the T2 is empty (so your problem is actually elsewhere; you probably simplified the query for us here).

**2) Query performance**

There are a few ways to write a query that gets records from table A not in table B.

However, they are not all equivalent, for example mysql creates different plans for

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID != T2.ID;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra               |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | T1    | system | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 |                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | T2    | system | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    0 | const row not found |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM T2);
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type   | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                          |
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | T1    | system | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 |                                |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | NULL  | NULL   | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL | no matching row in const table |
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)


mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID WHERE T2.ID IS NULL;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra               |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | T1    | system | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 |                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | T2    | system | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    0 | const row not found |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM T2 WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID);
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type   | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                          |
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | T1    | system | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 |                                |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | NULL  | NULL   | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL | no matching row in const table |
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, for the 4 different versions of the same query (they should all be equivalent if I didn't make stupid errors) you get two different execution plans.

Judging the plans from this example should **not** be done since the tables T1 and T2 contain only one and zero rows, respectively, and the plans **do** depend on the size, indexes and statistics. For production systems do compare the plans since I don't think mysql recognizes the equality of these queries.

**EDIT**
Ups, I did make a **stupid** error rushing on the interpretation of your query...

```
SELECT * FROM T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.t_id != T2.t_id
```

Facts
1) Left join

```
SELECT * FROM T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ...
```

will get all records from T1 regardless of the join criteria if there are no additional WHERE conditions (regardless of the join condition!)

2) the join condition determines which records are going to get joined to the records from T1 (determines cardinality and values of the attributes from T2)

so for a particular record from T1 it will

2a) fill attributes from T2 with NULLS only if and only if the join condition `T1.t_id != T2.t_id` is **FALSE** for **ALL** the records from T2. This occurs only if for a particular record in T1 every record in T2 has the same value of `t_id` as the record in T1.

2b) it will return **ALL** records from T2 if the join condition is TRUE, and this all is definitively not what you want

Here's an example continuing on your sample data

```
mysql> INSERT INTO `T2` (`id`, `title`, `t_id`) VALUES (8, 'xdad', 3);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID != T2.ID;
+----+--------+------+------+-------+------+
| id | title  | t_id | id   | title | t_id |
+----+--------+------+------+-------+------+
|  1 | apple  |    1 |    8 | xdad  |    3 |
|  2 | orange |    2 |    1 | dad   |    2 |
|  2 | orange |    2 |    8 | xdad  |    3 |
+----+--------+------+------+-------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The other three versions should indeed be equivalent

```
SELECT * FROM T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.t_id = T2.t_id WHERE T2.t_id IS NULL;
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT t_id FROM T2 WHERE T2.t_id = T1.t_id);
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE t_id NOT IN (SELECT t_id FROM T2);
```

The last version can also be written as

```
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE t_id NOT IN (SELECT t_id FROM T2 WHERE T2.t_id = T1.t_id);
```

Sorry for my de-concentration on the first try..

Comment: I have updated the problem above. It only works when using the 'WHERE ID NOT IN' clause

Answer (score 0):

Tried

**SELECT * 
FROM A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON ( A.t_id != B.t_id)**

?

Comment: Aren't `LEFT JOIN` / `LEFT OUTER JOIN`  the same?

Comment: LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN are two spellings for the same operation.